# PooledDBContextFactory Inject Context Asynchronously From Scoped Factory

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor, .net-7.0

I am looking to implement the PooledDBContextFactory within our Blazor Server Application.  We successfully implemented the basic DBContextFactory and are looking to further optimize the process with having the Contexts pooled.  We are multi-tenancy on a one db per client basis.  We need to set the connection string as the context is being created asynchronously.

I created my own DBContextFactory inheriting IDbContextFactory:

```
internal class MyDBContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyDBContext>
    {

        private readonly IDbContextFactory<MyDBContext> _pooledFactory;

        public MembershipDBContextFactory(IDbContextFactory<MembershipDBContext> pooledFactory)
        {
            _pooledFactory = pooledFactory;

        }

        public MembershipDBContext CreateDbContext()
        {
            var dbContext = _pooledFactory.CreateDbContext();


            var connectionStringPlaceHolder = _configuration.GetConnectionString("Connection");
            var newConnectionString = connectionStringPlaceHolder.Replace("{placeholder}", string);
            var currentConnectionString = dbContext.Database.GetConnectionString();
                        

            if (newConnectionString != currentConnectionString )
            {
                // make sure a possibly open connection is closed first as SetConnectionString() is documented
                // with "It may not be possible to change the connection string if existing connection, if any, is open."
                dbContext.Database.CloseConnection();

                dbContext.Database.SetConnectionString(newConnectionString);
            }

            return dbContext;
        }
    }
```

Here are the lines from the program.cs to implement the factory and inject the context.

```
builder.Services.AddPooledDbContextFactory<MembershipDBContext>(async (serviceProvider, dbContextBuilder) =>
{

    dbContextBuilder.UseSqlServer("temp");

}
);
builder.Services.AddScoped<MyDBContextFactory>();
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetService<MyDBContextFactory>().CreateDbContext());
```

I am able to inject the dbfactory to my blazor pages, and calling CreateDbContext will return the correct context the above method.  The problem is that I need to be able to call CreateDBContextAsync and have the connection string set correctly asynchronously.  I have tried creating the method as async and calling await _pooledFactory.CreateDbContextAsync() with no luck.  The issue could be in the
program.cs where the injection is attempted.  Here is what was tried:

`builder.Services.AddScoped(async sp => await sp.GetService<MyDBContextFactory>().CreateDbContextAsync())`

That resulted is my method not getting called at all.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.